# what does command sed -e 's/\(~\).*\(~\)// do to a text file?

Tags: sed

what does command   `sed -e 's/\(~\).*\(~\)//`  do  to a text file? I don't understand it. I came across it in my work.

Comment: What do you know? Do you know anything about sed? It is hard to know where to start, if you can't tell us what you know already. Should be start with, what Unix is, stdin, stdout, filters, regular expressions, .... A bit earlier, or a bit latter?

Answer (score 2):

The command (if you add a missing single quote at the end) will print all lines of the file to the terminal, but if there are at least two `~` (tilde) characters on any line, then the bit between the first and the last `~` will be removed by means of a substitution command (`s`) in `sed`.

Example:

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 ~ 4
1~2~3
Here is ~ the last ~ line ~ THE END
```

```
$ sed -e 's/\(~\).*\(~\)//' file
1 2 3 ~ 4
13
Here is  THE END
```

The `\(` and `\)` are not needed though (as there is no back-references used in the expression), and the `-e` can be left out too (as there is only one expression), so the command is equivalent to

```
sed 's/~.*~//' file
```

So, it does not *do* anything to the file itself, but it will read and modify the file's content, producing a processed text that you may then save in a new file with a redirection (`sed ... >newfile`).

---

A back-reference *could* be used in this command, like this:

```
sed 's/\(~\).*\1//' file
```

I.e., match a `~`, then some other text, and then the same thing that we matched in the first `\(...\)` group (a tilde).  But this does not save on typing or make the command easier to maintain or understand, so it would be no improvement on `sed 's/~.*~//' file`.